# WCF: One-way Callback Methods Executed on IOCP threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf

I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere.

On the client side, if I'm writing code to handle a callback method coming from the server, is this executed on IOCP thread?  If yes, I would expect that we should keep that callback method implementation efficient and quick.  If any blocking calls need to be made, then it would make sense to queue that callback response to a threadpool.

Can someone please confirm/deny my assumptions here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IO completion port as in a server, (eg. maybe on a server test system that needs to simulate 1000's of clients), then you are responsible for raising the user-space thread pool to wait on the completion port.  This pool can be large enough to allow many clients & so avoid a second-stage of queueing off to yet another thread pool.

If you are using overlapped IO completion callbacks, the callback is executed by the same thread that issued the ReadFileEx, (assuming your thread is correctly waiting on an alertable wait, (blahEx calls), that allows APC callbacks). If this thread is handling more than one client, then yes, this thread can get busy and you should queue off the buffer/socket/context/whatever to a threadpool thas can process the buffer and issue any reply.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, yes, it's on an IOCP. I think since the server is itself in the middle of an IOCP (since it's calling your callback), and since the client is in the middle of an IOCP, it's probably best to get out of there quick.

I am in the middle of the same issue, and I think mainly callbacks are used as "events" and are generally offloaded to the UI thread, or a different work Q.